# Meaning of identifier value in this context?

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate doc about transient object :- It has no persistent representation in the database and **no identifier value** has been assigned.
 What exactly is meant by identifier value here?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 states of object (instance) in hibernate.

**Transient**: The object is in transient state if it is just created but has **no primary key** (identifier) and **not associated with session**.

Hence, It has no persistent representation in the database and no identifier value has been assigned (I.e, nothing is done(save/update) in database related to the transient object).

**Persistent**: The object is in persistent state if session is **open** and you just **saved** the instance in the database or **retrieved** the instance from the database.

**Detached**: The object is in detached state if session is **closed**. After detached state, object comes to persistent state if you call lock() or update() method.

A persistent instance has a representation in the database, an identifier value and is associated with a Session. **You can make a transient instance persistent by associating it with a Session**.

The below code depicts all 3 states of a object in hibernate:

```
    Employee e1=new Employee();
    e1.setName("Rohit");
    Employee e2=new Employee();
    e2.setName("Glenn");
    //The above objects e1 & e2 are in transient state.

    SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory();
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();

    session.persist(e1);
    session.persist(e2);
    //now, the objects e1 & e2 are in persistent state.

    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    e1.setName("Mitchell");
    e1.setName("Joe");
    //now objects e1 & e2 are in detached state.
```